# TeXnicCenter: names of files in red instead of black, why?

Tags: texniccenter

In the files window the names of the files are most often in red and in some rare cases in black; would someone know why?

[image]

Comment: If it's anything like in TeXstudio, the red filenames probably mean that the editor somehow does not see these files (which does not necessarily mean that they do not exist or that LaTeX itself can't find them). But that's just an educated guess, since I've never used TeXnicCenter.

Comment: It's a new feature.  When all else fails, read the manual.

Answer (score 2):

Only if you had build an project TeXnicCenter shows you the the involved files.

Files that can be found by TeXnicCenter are printed in black, files in red can not be found by TeXnicCenter. But the red color of the filename does not mean, that the file can not be seen by the system.

For example in my project the `bib` file is printed in red, because I placed it in an special directory to be able to use this `bib` file with several projects. MiKTeX has no problems to find and use this `bib` file but TeXnicCenter does not know the path to that file.

Summarise: the red color of an filename shows you that there could be an problem with that file, but it could also be that TeXnicCenter is simply not able to see the path to it ...